# Is there any way to prevent EventListener from execting the code when it is being executed?

Tags: javascript, execution, addeventlistener

I am making a sliding menu using addEventListener, through which I am showing the hidden part of the menu when an item is clicked. However, when the item is being clicked again, the process of sliding starts over again. Is there any way to prevent the listener from executing the code which is being executed at the moment?

```
    var menuItemHidden = document.getElementById("hidden");

    // Unrolling

    function unroll() {

        var height = 0;

        var unroll1 = function() {

            height = height + 1;
            menuItem.style.height = height + "px";

            if (height == 100 ) {

                clearInterval(i);

            }

        };
        d.unrolling = "rolling";
        var i = window.setInterval(unroll1,1);

    }


    var menuItem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // I would like to prevent this code from being executed when it is currently
    // running, is there any way to achieve this?

    menuItem[2].addEventListener("click",unroll,true);
```

Comment: Can't you do this with CSS? If you can post some HTML I can see if it is possible in your situation, as you can do this much easier with CSS: `#hidden:active ~ #menuItem, #menuItem:hover {height:100px;}` for setting the height, and as you want to do it dynamically: `#menuItem{transition:height .1s ease;}` to do the smoothness.

Comment: Just made a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tb3S8/), to show that you can do this much better and cleaner using CSS.

Comment: Yes, I know that this can be achieved with CSS and that approach is easier and clearer, I just wanted to try it in JavaScript, thanks for effort anyway. :)

Comment: Any specific reason why You want to try it? Is a solution where you have a class for a collapsed menu item and a class for a rolled out one, and just change change that with JavaScript enough? Or are you just looking for a JavaScript way to have a smooth transition?

Answer (score 3):

Sure - just set a boolean flag that denotes whether the function is currently being executed. In your handler, check the flag and then update it once it's complete.

For example:

```
var menuItemHidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
var running = false;
// Unrolling

function unroll() {
  if (!running) {
    .. running = true ..

    .. execute code..

    .. running = false ..
  }
}
```

If you don't want to pollute the global namespace with `running`, just use a closure.

```
var unroll = (function() {
  var running = false;
  return function() {
    .. unroll code ..
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to wrap it in an answer:
This is **not** an answer to your question, but I don't see any reason to set the height every millisecond using JS while this can be done more dynamically with CSS. This also means the menu going back (height getting less).
In CSS for a click on #hidden you want to select `#hidden:active`, and then select the next element `#menuItem`. You do that with `~`, but if the `#menuItem` is **inside** the `#hidden`, you want to select the menu item with `+`.

```
#hidden:active ~ #menuItem, #hidden:hover ~ #menuItem, #menuItem:hover {
    height:100px;   /*This sets the height when you hover over the hidden div or click on it. To prevent the menu from disappearing when you hover over it #menuItem:hover is added*/
}
#menuItem {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height .1s ease; /*This is for the animation, so that the div moves slowly and not in an instant*/
}
```

Conclusion:
Unless you have a very special reason, use CSS. It's cleaner, easier and doesn't require a script (which some browsers and adblock plus do not execute).

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/tb3S8/1/)